# forEach loop: Sum multiple values in the same Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I'm using `find` to get values on my variable, but when this variable return multiples values, my condition can't read them.

What I need is sum this variable values, returning just one number.

**Code:**

```
mail.forEach(function(m) {

    var nresult = $("#dat").contents()
        .find("td:contains('" + m.hexEncode() + "')" )
        .length;

    return nresult;

});
```

I need to keep this `forEach` function - is the only way to keep my external data working, so, this will return, in that case, this values: `0,0,1,1,0`, and I need just `2` on return.

How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: is `nresult` an array of values?

Comment: I think it is. I mean, if I use some script deleting the past value and adding a new one, just one value return. But when I use something like append, I get all values returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT (after chat) :
You can modify your `return` statement to do something like that :

```
var res = mail.map(function(m) { 

    var nresult = $("#dat").contents() 
    .find("td:contains('" + m.hexEncode() + "')" ) 
    .length; 
    return nresult;

}).reduce(function(a,b){ return a+b });
```

So the reduce function will execute `a+b` on the array returned by `map()`.

You can then use your variable res as you want.

Comment: Log - Cannot read property 'reduce'. Thanks, Tomisol, for your answer. You know how can I change that?

Comment: Which one gives you this error ? The return statement with nresult ?

Comment: No, the console log of entire page when I run the script

Comment: Oh, sorry, the second. The first return a null value

Comment: Which call gives you this `0,0,1,1,0` in your code ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105317/discussion-between-zeca-novaes-and-tomisol).

Comment: I can't believe it! hahaha Thank you!